# Есть ли вероятность положить сервер?

Tags: клиент-сервер, ddos

Хочу спарить данные с сервера гос организации, 230к строк  24 колонок. Есть ли вероятность, что он упадет? На какую передачу обычно рассчитаны сервера? Или нет смысла об этом даже задумываться?

Comment: Лучше ставить вопрос не в строках, а в числе запросов в секунду. Нормальные сервера настроены на тысячи, а то и на миллионы запросов в секунду (у соцсетей такие). Ну плюс обычно ставят какую-нибудь защиту от `DDOS` атак, так что возможно вам просто не дадут сделать больше скольки-то запросов за какое-то время, а потом сервер будет запрещать вам запросы какое-то время. Тут только пробовать. Если нужно делать много запросов с одного сервера, то часто приходится пользоваться платными прокси и на другие всякие исхищрения идти.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, объем данных в 230к строк выглядит смешным.

Если растянуть парсинг на день (ну, Вы же не гонитесь за то, чтобы первыми в мире спарсить эти данные?) - то, скорее всего, такой нагрузки на сервер никто даже не заметит

Answer (score 0):

Так, ещё раз.. У тебя есть запасной сервер, ты на нём это все проводить будешь? Потому, что ну.. Очевидно  да, я бы даже не рискнул делать что-то такое на сервере, который всегда должен быть в сети, ибо данные - казённые, зачем тебе такой стресс? Когда есть вполне конкретный риск, то тут даже задумываться не стоит, а то будет из серии "хотел как лучше, а получилось как всегда", с тебя же потом спросят, причины никого волновать не будут

К тому же у нас в СНГ в гос. учреждениях обычно такое железо, что.. Кхм. Сам знаешь, лучше не рисковать; некоторые офисные пк то всё ещё даже на ХРюше стоят, а администрирование более сложных систем до твоего прихода могло быть и вовсе никакущим, так что..

Comment: Я понимаю, что работодатель и альтернатив мог не предоставить, но это всё в любом случае нужно не под твою ответственность, ты просто исполнитель в соотв. с нормативами, скажем так, потому что если что-то пойдёт не так, то с тебя сдерут по полной хд

Comment: Хех понял тогда буду по частям грузить)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сервер не упал попробуй ParseHub, Octoparse, Data Miner или Import.io.  Там можно настроить интервалы между запросами. Или парси данные мелкими частями в многопоточном режиме.